# Exception thrown at 0x00007FF795014E96 in Project1.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation writing location 0x00000000705B49C0

Tags: c, arrays, malloc

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>
void spyral(int boyut)
{
    int i;
    int*a = malloc(boyut * sizeof(int*));
    for (i = 0; i < boyut; i++)
    {
        a[i] = i + 1; //program is erroring here
    }
    for (i = 0; i < boyut; i++)
    {
        printf("%d", a[i]);
    }
    /*int x = 5;
    int y = 5;
    int** a = malloc(x * sizeof(int*));
    for (int i = 0; i < y; i++) {
        a[i] = malloc(sizeof(int*) * y);
    }*/
}
int main()
{
    spyral(6);
}
```

I want to send a variable to function from main, this code is not working on visual studio but this works on dev-c++. I want to work on visual studio, what is the problem?

Comment: An array of pointers is not a pointer to an array.

Comment: so what should i do? what is that meaning?

Comment: `boyut * sizeof(int*)` should be `boyut * sizeof(int)`. You're trying to allocate space for 6 integers.

Comment: The only problem I see is that `#include <stdlib.h>` is missing.

Comment: thank you @melpomene , stdlib solved my problem, the * at sizeof(int *) what is that meaning? when should i use that?

Comment: It means the same thing it does in `int*a`. When you do `sizeof (int)` you're asking for the size of a variable of type `int`. When you do `sizeof (int *)`, you're asking for the size of a variable of type pointer to `int`.

Comment: If including `<stdlib.h>` fixed your problem, you should also have gotten complaints from the compiler about `a = malloc(...)`. Something about initializing a pointer from an integer. Don't ignore compiler warnings.

Comment: @melpomene http://prntscr.com/nej7py i see this warnings, that i even a little dont know

Comment: codes are like these now http://prntscr.com/nej8z7